# How can i get beep audio input from mic and process it in java

Tags: java, audio

I want to calculate the max, min and average time for which the beep was high from mic input.

Following is the code to capture an playbak it from mic. But I want to sense the beep sound coming and calculate time of each beep.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class AudioCapture01 extends JFrame{

  boolean stopCapture = false;
  ByteArrayOutputStream
  byteArrayOutputStream;
  AudioFormat audioFormat;
  TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
  AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
  SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

  public static void main(String args[]){
    new AudioCapture01();
  }//end main

  public AudioCapture01(){      //constructor
    final JButton captureBtn = new JButton("Capture");
    final JButton stopBtn = new JButton("Stop");
    final JButton playBtn = new JButton("Playback");

    captureBtn.setEnabled(true);
    stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
    playBtn.setEnabled(false);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //Register anonymous listeners
    captureBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          captureBtn.setEnabled(false);
          stopBtn.setEnabled(true);
          playBtn.setEnabled(false);
          //Capture input data from the microphone until the Stop button is clicked.
          captureAudio();
        }//end actionPerformed
      }//end ActionListener
    );//end addActionListener()
    getContentPane().add(captureBtn);

    stopBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          captureBtn.setEnabled(true);
          stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
          playBtn.setEnabled(true);
          //Terminate the capturing of input data from the microphone.
          stopCapture = true;
        }//end actionPerformed
      }//end ActionListener
    );//end addActionListener()
    getContentPane().add(stopBtn);

    playBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          //Play back all of the data that was saved during capture.
          playAudio();
        }//end actionPerformed
      }//end ActionListener
    );//end addActionListener()
    getContentPane().add(playBtn);

    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("Capture/Playback Demo");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300,70);
    setVisible(true);
  }//end constructor

  //This method captures audio input from a microphone and saves it in a ByteArrayOutputStream object.
  private void captureAudio(){
    try{
      //Get everything set up for capture
      audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
      DataLine.Info dataLineInfo =new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class,audioFormat);
      targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
      targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
      targetDataLine.start();

      //Create a thread to capture the microphone data and start it
      // running.  It will run until the Stop button is clicked.
      Thread captureThread =new Thread(new CaptureThread());
      captureThread.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      System.exit(0);
    }//end catch
  }//end captureAudio method

  //This method plays back the audio
  // data that has been saved in the
  // ByteArrayOutputStream
  private void playAudio() {
    try{
      //Get everything set up for
      // playback.
      //Get the previously-saved data
      // into a byte array object.
      byte audioData[] =byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
      //Get an input stream on the
      // byte array containing the data
      InputStream byteArrayInputStream= new ByteArrayInputStream(audioData);
      AudioFormat audioFormat =getAudioFormat();
      audioInputStream =new AudioInputStream(byteArrayInputStream,audioFormat,audioData.length/audioFormat.getFrameSize());
      DataLine.Info dataLineInfo =new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,audioFormat);
      sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
      sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
      sourceDataLine.start();

      //Create a thread to play back
      // the data and start it
      // running.  It will run until
      // all the data has been played
      // back.
      Thread playThread =new Thread(new PlayThread());
      playThread.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      System.exit(0);
    }//end catch
  }//end playAudio

  //This method creates and returns an
  // AudioFormat object for a given set
  // of format parameters.  If these
  // parameters don't work well for
  // you, try some of the other
  // allowable parameter values, which
  // are shown in comments following
  // the declarations.
  private AudioFormat getAudioFormat(){
    float sampleRate = 8000.0F;     //8000,11025,16000,22050,44100
    int sampleSizeInBits = 16;      //8,16
    int channels = 1;               //1,2
    boolean signed = true;          //true,false
    boolean bigEndian = false;      //true,false
    return new AudioFormat(sampleRate,sampleSizeInBits,channels,signed,bigEndian);
  }//end getAudioFormat
//===================================//
```

Inner class to capture data from microphone

```
class CaptureThread extends Thread {
  //An arbitrary-size temporary holding buffer
  byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];
  public void run(){
    byteArrayOutputStream =new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    stopCapture = false;
    try{//Loop until stopCapture is set
        // by another thread that
        // services the Stop button.
      while(!stopCapture){
        //Read data from the internal
        // buffer of the data line.
        int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer,0,tempBuffer.length);
        if(cnt > 0){
          //Save data in output stream object.
          byteArrayOutputStream.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
        }//end if
      }//end while
      byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      System.exit(0);
    }//end catch
  }//end run
}//end inner class CaptureThread

//===================================//
//Inner class to play back the data that was saved.

class PlayThread extends Thread{
  byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

  public void run(){
    try{
      int cnt;
      //Keep looping until the input read method returns -1 for empty stream.
      while((cnt = audioInputStream.
        read(tempBuffer, 0,
            tempBuffer.length)) != -1){
        if(cnt > 0){
          //Write data to the internal buffer of the data line
          // where it will be delivered to the speaker.
          sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
        }//end if
      }//end while
      //Block and wait for internal buffer of the data line to empty.
      sourceDataLine.drain();
      sourceDataLine.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      System.exit(0);
    }//end catch
  }//end run
}//end inner class PlayThread
}//end outer class AudioCapture01.java
```

I am able to capture and playback the audio but I can't sense the audio. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you do that? Add some information/sample.